# what is the difference between service oriented architecture and modular monolithic

Tags: architecture, soa, modular-monolith

What is the difference between service-oriented architecture and modular monolithic architecture? In service-oriented architecture, there is a concept called a service. Is a service the same as a module in modular monolithic architecture?

Comment: The short answer is yes. *Unlike the traditional monolith, modular monoliths attempt to establish bounded context by segmenting code into individual feature modules* - [source](https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/tip/Understanding-the-modular-monolith-and-its-ideal-use-cases). Do you need further elaboration?